# NoMethodError undefined method 'convert_key' when using Mongoid in Ruby 2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

A project that was working fine has started throwing this error after I upgraded from Ruby 2.0 to 2.2. It happens when I try and access a mongo database, even for a simple `Table.all.to_a`

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `convert_key' for {"database"=>"db_name"}:Mongo::Options::Redacted):
```

Here db_name is the actual name of the database which does exist on the ports configured in mongoid.yml. I'm using mongoid (5.0.0).

How do I resolve this error?

**Updated**
I printed out a more useful error which traced back to the file:

.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.1.1/lib/mongo/options/redacted.rb:64:

To the code:

```
  def has_key?(key)
    super(convert_key(key))
  end
  alias_method :key?, :has_key?
```

with a key value of connect.

I'm still not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Version of mongoid?  My guess is something is wrong in your yml file.

Comment: mongoid (5.0.0), I deleted my yml file, recreated it with: rails g mongoid:config, then just changed the db name in that file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the version of mongo in the project gem file to 2.1.0, where previously it had automatically downloaded 2.1.1. I then executed `bundler update`. This solved the problem. I then switched the version in my gem file back to 2.1.1 explicitly and ran `bundler update` again. The problem was still fixed! So I guess somehow the mongo gem had been corrupted as I moved the project to rbenv Ruby 2.2.0 from 2.0.0